# C# trim method not working inside an action

Tags: c#, delegates

I want to trim a certain property of all the entities. But this `entity.ForEach(x => x.PropertyName.Trim());` doesn't seem to work. After the execution of the action the property still has white space in it. So any idea how to make this easily?

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: Trim returns the value you want.

Comment: Using `.ForEach()` is a bad idea anyway.  Just use a regular `foreach` loop and remember that strings are immutable so you have to assign the result of `Trim()` to something.

Comment: @maccettura why using a foreach is a bad idea?

Comment: @john Eric Lippert [has a nice blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/) about this.  Expressions shouldn't cause side effects, they should compute a value.  Using the `foreach` loop statement makes your intent clear and you have the added ability in your case to assign the variables the results of `variable.Trim()`

Answer (score 0):

Either create a new list object (y) and do recreate the object list with trimmed values. This is functional programming.

`entity.ForEach(x => y.Add(new entity{ PropertyName = x.PropertyName.Trim()}));`

I posted below code previously - will not work because the entity list object is **immutable**. I apologize for the mistake.(Ignore the below code)

```
entity.ForEach(x => x.PropertyName = x.PropertyName.Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you shouldn't use the `.ForEach()` method, you should use a `foreach` loop.  Secondly, the actual problem you are encountering is that strings are immutable.  When you call `.Trim()` the string itself is not being modified, `Trim()` returns a *new* string so you need to assign that to something:

```
foreach(var e in entity)
{
    e.PropertyName = e.PropertyName.Trim();
}
```

You might want to work on your naming too. `entity` implies a *singular*, where you can see very clearly that it is a collection of something since we iterate it.  Maybe it should be `entities`?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
entity.ForEach(x => 
{
    x.PropertyName = x.PropertyName.Trim();
});
```

You never assigned the new string value returned from Trim() Method.

> And if you want to remove all the spaces

```
entity.ForEach(x => 
{
    x.PropertyName = x.PropertyName.Trim().Replace(" ", String.Empty);
});
```

Comment: @maccettura this is Classic Action in c#. I don't think so it's that hard to read.

Comment: You should probably [read this too](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/) then

Comment: @maccettura Agreeing to the legend but that again is a matter of point of view.

Comment: And @maccettura that article is written back in 2009 and world of developers has been changed so much in 9 years.

Comment: The article was written by one of the language design team members and an all around expert in .NET.   The core argument in the article does not change because it was 9 years ago.  The language is still designed in one way, and the `ForEach()` method of `List` breaks that pattern.  It should likely have never been included in the language in the first place (why do you think they haven't done the same for `IEnumerable`?).

Comment: even after 9 years if c# is keeping this as a language feature, then I guess if it's there I'll use it if you don't feel good about using it please don't use it but please don't enforce that someone on for not using it.

Comment: @maccettura and if they think that's not the good idea to use it why they included that in the first place???

Comment: Do you understand the difficulty and impact removing parts of the framework are? 
 The framework needs to stay as backward compatible as possible.  What happens to all the bad code writers out there that used this method and now .NET version X has removed it... Their code bases will break.  Sometimes people make mistakes, sometimes those mistakes take much more to correct than its worth.

Comment: Its _very_ clear that it is considered a mistake because they never implemented the same thing in `IEnumerable` which would have a far greater reach and use than a `List` method.  You are defending something that has no business being defended.  Feel free to write all the counter intuitive code you want, but PRs with that code would be rejected anywhere I have ever worked.

Comment: So i guess by that logic this feature is staying till internity so better learn how to use it then ignoring it.

Comment: the feature already exists. It’s called a `foreach` loop. Besides `goto` still exists, I _hope_ you are not using that!  I’m done trying to argue with you though, your bad code habits are ultimately not my problem.